# Collect SQL statements and dump SQL with Rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I want to record all executed SQL statements by ActiveRecord of a given block/method and then get the SQL dump of these. 
I'm writing a script where I insert into a database and then get a sql dump to replay these inserts.

What I'd like to do would be something like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do 
  Model.create!
  # other SQL statements
end.to_sql
```

or

```
results = ActiveRecord::Base.record do 
  Model.create!
  # other SQL statements
end
```

I know this doesn't work. The `record` method doesn't exist and `to_sql` only works with relations.

All I can come up with is a database dump from SQL like `mysqldump -uroot -p database -r utf8.dump`. But can this be done within Rails?

Comment: Although I'm not sure how to achieve this in rails, but I'm interested in knowing why you would want to do that instead of database dump?

Comment: With a database dump I would get the complete state of a database for a certain time whereas if I record all SQL I could then execute all these statements for different databases with the same schema.